# How to install QCustomPlot for PyQt5 on Arch Linux

Tags: pyqt5, sip, archlinux, qcustomplot, python-sip

I want to use QCustomPlot with PyQt5 on Arch Linux but I'm having trouble installing it. I already installed the `sip` package but the setup fails with the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sipdistutils'
```

Link to repo: https://github.com/dimv36/QCustomPlot-PyQt5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install both `python-sip` and `sip` otherwise the setup will fail:

```
pacman -S python-pyqt5 python-sip sip
pip install git+https://github.com/dimv36/QCustomPlot-PyQt5
```

[Some examples](https://github.com/dimv36/QCustomPlot-PyQt5/tree/master/examples)